# What is the relationship between covering designs (La Jolla Covering Repository) and linear block codes?

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

In many papers I have been reading, bioengineers are utilizing covering sets from Dan Gordon's [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/table.html) to design custom Modified Hamming Codes (MHD).
These MHDs have custom codeword lengths and desired Hamming weights, that I see some have been using to create codewords outside the (7,4) Hamming code taught in textbooks.

I'm trying to better understand the link between covering designs and linear block codes. Namely, I'm not understanding how *(v, k, t)* covering design inform the property of a linear block code (ie. what's the Hamming distance? rate? error-detection capacity? error-correcting capacity)? Why can covering designs be used to make a linear block at all?

For clarity, a *(v, k, t)* covering design is defined below:

> A (v,k,t)-covering design is a collection of k-element subsets, called blocks, of {1,2,…,v}, such that any t-element subset is contained in at least one block.

Comment: for clarity point out a (non paywall) paper where MHDs are constructed and state the parameters of the MHD that results (at least)